# Error 500 for Nokia API on IE

Tags: here-api

We have a problem with your API. When we try to receive data from an address using IE,
we receive a 500 error from your API.

Watching the generated url to access this information, I get the following:

### Chrome

```
http://api.places.lbs.maps.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/search/?callback=nokia.places.comm.data.clb[%22101%22]&app_id=ywQ7oG0pDVf4baOfgD63&app_code=FhWanW-p-KHXfPpqWIRDOg&Accept-Language=en-US&size=10&q=Fuentes%20Acebedo%20%2023%2COviedo%2C33006%2CAsturias&at=40.41764566275246,-3.7002038955688477
```

### IE

```
http://api.places.lbs.maps.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/search/?callback=nokia.places.comm.data.clb["101"]&app_id=ywQ7oG0pDVf4baOfgD63&app_code=FhWanW-p-KHXfPpqWIRDOg&Accept-Language=en-US&size=10&q=Fuentes%20acebedo%20%2023%2Coviedo%2C33006%2Casturias&at=40.41764566275246,-3.7002038955688476
```

The only difference is that:
IE --> ["101"]
Chrome --> [%22101%22]

If you go to the url that I specified for IE, you will see you get a 500 error.

You have a solution for this error?

tnks!

### Full error

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /places/v1/discover/search/. Reason: 

    Server Error

Caused by:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:841)
at pbapi.Uri$.fromString(Uri.scala:37)
at pbapi.http.RequestSummary.toCurl(RequestSummary.scala:45)
at pbapi.monitoring.Incident$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Incident.scala:41)
at pbapi.monitoring.Incident$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Incident.scala:41)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133)
at pbapi.monitoring.Incident$.apply(Incident.scala:41)
at pbapi.monitoring.LoggingIncidentReporter.createIncident(LoggingIncidentReporter.scala:46)
at pbapi.monitoring.LoggingIncidentReporter.requestProcessingError(LoggingIncidentReporter.scala:34)
at pbapi.web.springmvc.GenericExceptionResolver.resolveException(GenericExceptionResolver.scala:79)
at spring.helpers.PlacesApiDispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(PlacesApiDispatcherServlet.scala:91)
at spring.helpers.PlacesApiDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(PlacesApiDispatcherServlet.scala:72)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:648)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1336)
at org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.ContinuationFilter.doFilter(ContinuationFilter.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:242)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
at pbapi.web.preprocessors.CorsPreprocessor.go(CorsPreprocessor.scala:20)
at pbapi.web.preprocessors.CorsPreprocessor.doFilter(CorsPreprocessor.scala:12)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
at pbapi.web.preprocessors.RequestAttributor.doFilter(RequestAttributor.scala:25)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
at pbapi.web.preprocessors.Query2Header.doFilter(Query2Header.scala:30)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:453)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:559)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 100: http://api.places.lbs.maps.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/search/?callback=nokia.places.comm.data.clb["101"]&app_id=ywQ7oG0pDVf4baOfgD63&app_code=FhWanW-p-KHXfPpqWIRDOg&Accept-Language=en-US&size=10&q=Fuentes%20acebedo%20%2023%2Coviedo%2C33006%2Casturias&at=40.41764566275246,-3.7002038955688476

at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2810)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2983)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3073)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3015)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:577)
at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:839)
... 53 more

Caused by:

java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 100: http://api.places.lbs.maps.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/search/?callback=nokia.places.comm.data.clb["101"]&app_id=ywQ7oG0pDVf4baOfgD63&app_code=FhWanW-p-KHXfPpqWIRDOg&Accept-Language=en-US&size=10&q=Fuentes%20acebedo%20%2023%2Coviedo%2C33006%2Casturias&at=40.41764566275246,-3.7002038955688476

at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2810)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2983)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3073)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3015)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:577)
at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:839)
at pbapi.Uri$.fromString(Uri.scala:37)
at pbapi.http.RequestSummary.toCurl(RequestSummary.scala:45)
at pbapi.monitoring.Incident$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Incident.scala:41)
at pbapi.monitoring.Incident$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Incident.scala:41)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133)
at pbapi.monitoring.Incident$.apply(Incident.scala:41)
at pbapi.monitoring.LoggingIncidentReporter.createIncident(LoggingIncidentReporter.scala:46)
at pbapi.monitoring.LoggingIncidentReporter.requestProcessingError(LoggingIncidentReporter.scala:34)
at pbapi.web.springmvc.GenericExceptionResolver.resolveException(GenericExceptionResolver.scala:79)
at spring.helpers.PlacesApiDispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(PlacesApiDispatcherServlet.scala:91)
at spring.helpers.PlacesApiDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(PlacesApiDispatcherServlet.scala:72)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:648)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1336)
at org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.ContinuationFilter.doFilter(ContinuationFilter.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:242)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
at pbapi.web.preprocessors.CorsPreprocessor.go(CorsPreprocessor.scala:20)
at pbapi.web.preprocessors.CorsPreprocessor.doFilter(CorsPreprocessor.scala:12)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
at pbapi.web.preprocessors.RequestAttributor.doFilter(RequestAttributor.scala:25)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
at pbapi.web.preprocessors.Query2Header.doFilter(Query2Header.scala:30)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:453)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:559)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)


Powered by Jetty://
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution is quite simple.
Use version 2.2.3 instead of 2.2.0